# How do you change ActiveAdmin password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I got ActiveAdmin running with admin@example.com//password, but I want to change these credentials. Anyone know how to change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an answer from the ActiveAdmin wiki:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Your-First-Admin-Resource%3A-AdminUser

Comment: This works to create new users, what about changing passwords though?

Comment: The link is your answer now routes to a "Create new page" instead of a wiki page with content. Answers should include more than just a link.

Answer (score 39):

Best way to do this would be to change it from the rails console :

```
    admin = AdminUser.find_by_email("admin@domain.com")
    admin.password = "newPassword"
    admin.save
```

Answer (score 11):

When you install ActiveAdmin using the generator, you'll find a migration called `{timestamp}_devise_create_admin_users.rb` in your `db/migrate` folder.

Find and change this line to whatever you want:

```
AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

Keep in mind though, that this is just the seed password, and is being exposed as plaintext. What you might want to do is set up the Devise controllers to have a password change action. Check out the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) and the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at app/admin/admin_users.rb will enable change password for edit admin user.

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  index do
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
    end
    f.buttons
  end  
end
```